# Use Java Robot To Hit Enter On Windows Firewall Prompt

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, firewall, awtrobot

I'm trying to create a Java program that will assist in installing a certain .exe file. However, when the installation .exe is run on certain Windows machines, a Windows firewall prompt is at first displayed. Is there anyway to use Java Robot class to hit enter on this prompt? The following expected code doesn't seem to work:

```
final Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: I don't think the Allow button has the focus by default.

Comment: If it were possible to do this, it would be a major security flaw.

Comment: The correct approach is to create the necessary firewall rule *before* running the installer.  There is a Windows API for doing so, though you'll need admin privilege.